# Use extractTextPlugin and postCss plugins in Webpack 2

Tags: webpack, postcss

I am migrating from webpack v1 to v2. I followed the official doc to update `webpack.config.js`:

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                    'css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[path][name]_[local]--[hash:base64:8]',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ],
            }),
            exclude: [...]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: 'css-loader',
            }),
            include: [...]
        }
    ]
},
...
/**
 * postcss: [
 *   nested(),
 *   autoprefixer(),
 *   values
 * ]
 */
```

My problem is the postcss plugins(nested, autoprefixer, values). Webpack 2 didn't support custom property any more, and suggested use `options`.

I tried the `options` and `plugins: () => [nested, autoprefixer, values]` but can't make it work.

What's the proper way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use a `postcss.config.js` file which exports an object with the options (see [Postcss usage](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#usage)). Your config would look like this (omitting the import statements):

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    nested(),
    autoprefixer(),
    values
  ]
}
```

But if you want to, you can specify it directly in the webpack config (as shown in [Postcss options](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#options)):

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      'css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[path][name]_[local]--[hash:base64:8]',
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: () => [nested(), autoprefixer(), values]
        }
      }
    ]
  })
  exclude: [...]
},
```

Note that the options are on the loader itself, not the entire rule.